# Passing Binding Parameters to PL SQL Update Statements

Tags: c#, sql, dml

I have done this numerous times with SELECT statements with no problems. I also understand that DML PL SQL statements don't allow binded parameters in "some" instances but I have gotten UPDATE statements to work. It has by no means been consist though. I don't know what else to do with my statements. Below I have taken part of my code that deals with the UPDATE statements. I am basically passing parameters to my statements (in particular the sampleID and testID variable both are declared as integers) but the statement contains zeros in the places of the variables. Which means it is not recognizing the values that have been assigned to the sampleID and testID variables. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. The first update command (ucommand) works but the last two don't. I'm at a lost here.

```
if(!row["field_result"].ToString().Equals(""))
{
    //Build SQL commands to address the field result
    string ucommand = "UPDATE CC_MSD_LIMS_STAGING SET FIELD_RESULT = '" + @locfield + "', CREATEDDT = SYSDATE"
        + " WHERE MONITORING_ID = " + @locmon_ID + " AND IPACS_SAMPLE_ID = " + @locipacs_ID + " AND FACILITY_ID = "
        + @locfacil_ID + " AND POLLUTANT = '" + @locpoll + "'";
    string idcmd = "SELECT SAMPLEID FROM LIM_SAMPLE WHERE SAMPLENUMBER = (SELECT PRIM_SAM_KEY FROM CC_MSD_LIMS_STAGING "
        + "WHERE MONITORING_ID = " + @locmon_ID + " AND IPACS_SAMPLE_ID = " + @locipacs_ID + " AND FACILITY_ID = "
        + @locfacil_ID + " AND POLLUTANT = '" + @locpoll + "')";
    string testcmd = "SELECT TESTID FROM LIM_TESTGROUPTESTS WHERE TESTGROUPID = (SELECT TESTGROUPID FROM LIM_TESTGROUP WHERE "
        + "TESTGROUPNAME = '" + @locpoll + "' AND ACTIVE = 1 AND PUBLISHED = 1)";
    string upd1cmd = "UPDATE LIM_SAMPLETESTRUNRESULT SET SAMPLETESTRUNRESULTRAW = '" + @locfield + "', SAMPLETESTRUNRESULTCALC "
        + "= '" + @locfield + "', SAMPLETESTRUNRESULTREPORT = '" + @locfield + "', SAMPLETESTRUNRESULTSTATUS = 3, EDITEDDT "
        + "= SYSDATE, EDITEDBY = 128 WHERE SAMPLEID = " + @sampleID + " AND TESTID = " + @testID;
    string upd2cmd = "UPDATE LIM_SAMPLETESTRESULTPROCESSES SET PROCESSSTATUS = 3.3, PROCESSCOMPLETEDT = SYSDATE, PROCESSCOMPLETEBY "
        + "= 128 WHERE SAMPLEID = " + @sampleID + " AND TESTID = " + @testID;

    //Execute commands
    try
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(ucommand, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@locmon_ID", locmon_ID);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@locfacil_ID", locfacil_ID);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@locipacs_ID", locipacs_ID);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@locpoll", locpoll);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@locfield", locfield);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.CommandText = "COMMIT WORK";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.CommandText = idcmd;
            sampleID = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            cmd.CommandText = testcmd;
            testID = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        }

        using (OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand(upd1cmd, conn))
        {
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@sampleID", sampleID);
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@testID", testID);
            cmd1.CommandText = upd1cmd;
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd1.CommandText = "COMMIT WORK";
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd1.CommandText = upd2cmd;
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd1.CommandText = "COMMIT WORK";
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception f)
    {
        //Log.Error("Problems with the field results.");
    }
}
```

[image: the command that is passed to Oracle (notice the zeros)]

Comment: Remove the quotes around the parameters placeholders

Comment: `string ucommand = "UPDATE CC_MSD_LIMS_STAGING SET FIELD_RESULT = @locfield, CREATEDDT = SYSDATE 
        WHERE MONITORING_ID = @locmon_ID AND IPACS_SAMPLE_ID = @locipacs_ID AND FACILITY_ID =         @locfacil_ID + AND POLLUTANT = @locpoll";`

Comment: If I remove the quotes, I get the error "Cannot convert int to string". Both the sampleID and testID parameters are integers. The ucommand works. It's the updcmd1 and updcmd2 that don't work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. All of the parameters are passing there respective values except sampleID and testID. These two are also in the string statements updcmd1 and updcmd2. So I'm not sure what you mean by your last statement @Steve

Comment: I have removed my previous comment. However I don't undestand where do you get that error message. When you write a parameterized query you don't insert a value for a field inside the commandtext. You just put placeholders for the parameters inside the commandtext. They are just text not variables. Then every named placeholder  @something should have its parameter value added to the Command parameters collection. And each parameter should have also its type specified. Use _cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OracleDbType.XXXX).Value = value_ By the way the prefix for parameters in oracle is `:`

Comment: I get the error message if I replace ` cmd1.Parameters.Add("@sampleID", sampleID);` with ` cmd1.Parameters.Add(@sampleID, sampleID);`

Comment: _cmd1.Parameters.Add("@sampleID", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = sampleID_ assuming the variable sampleID is an integer and the database field expects an integer. Otherwise you should choose the correct OracleDbType from the enumeration. Do not pass parameters with a different type from what the db expects

Comment: Even if I change `cmd1.Parameters.Add("@sampleID", sampleID);`to `cmd1.Parameters.Add("@sampleID",OracleDbType.Int32).Value = sampleID;` I still get the same statement with the zeros the my pic shows. If I create a string command like the ucommand you displayed previously, then the placeholders become part of the string and is passed to Oracle as such. So I will have an update statement with commercial at signs in it instead of actual variable values.

Comment: That's the whole point in using parameters. You don't need to set values in the commandtext but just placeholders. It is the db engine job to use your command.Parameters collection to do the appropriate use of the parameter value

Comment: In order to better understand the situation. Could you please add to your question the code you are using with my variations? Just the first command is enough

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with this I figured out that I really didn't need to pass parameters for my last two update statements. I just built the string statements based off the values that were already collected. So I recreated the code block as the following and it worked, thanks @Steve for time:

```
if (!row["field_result"].ToString().Equals(""))
                                {
                                    //Build SQL commands to address the field result
                                    string ucommand = "UPDATE CC_MSD_LIMS_STAGING SET FIELD_RESULT = '" + @locfield + "', CREATEDDT = SYSDATE"
                                        + " WHERE MONITORING_ID = " + @locmon_ID + " AND IPACS_SAMPLE_ID = " + @locipacs_ID + " AND FACILITY_ID = "
                                        + @locfacil_ID + " AND POLLUTANT = '" + @locpoll + "'";
                                    string idcmd = "SELECT SAMPLEID FROM LIM_SAMPLE WHERE SAMPLENUMBER = (SELECT PRIM_SAM_KEY FROM CC_MSD_LIMS_STAGING "
                                        + "WHERE MONITORING_ID = " + @locmon_ID + " AND IPACS_SAMPLE_ID = " + @locipacs_ID + " AND FACILITY_ID = "
                                        + @locfacil_ID + " AND POLLUTANT = '" + @locpoll + "')";
                                    string testcmd = "SELECT TESTID FROM LIM_TESTGROUPTESTS WHERE TESTGROUPID = (SELECT TESTGROUPID FROM LIM_TESTGROUP WHERE "
                                        + "TESTGROUPNAME = '" + @locpoll + "' AND ACTIVE = 1 AND PUBLISHED = 1)"; 

                                    //Execute commands
                                    try
                                    {
                                        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(ucommand, conn))
                                        {
                                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@locmon_ID", locmon_ID);
                                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@locfacil_ID", locfacil_ID);
                                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@locipacs_ID", locipacs_ID);
                                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@locpoll", locpoll);
                                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@locfield", locfield);
                                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                            cmd.CommandText = "COMMIT WORK";
                                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                            cmd.CommandText = idcmd;
                                            sampleID = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                                            cmd.CommandText = testcmd;
                                            testID = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                                        }

                                        string upd1cmd = "";

                                        using (OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand(upd1cmd,conn))
                                        {
                                            upd1cmd = "UPDATE LIM_SAMPLETESTRUNRESULT SET SAMPLETESTRUNRESULTRAW = '" + locfield + "', SAMPLETESTRUNRESULTCALC "
                                            + "= '" + locfield + "', SAMPLETESTRUNRESULTREPORT = '" + locfield + "', SAMPLETESTRUNRESULTSTATUS = 3, EDITEDDT "
                                            + "= SYSDATE, EDITEDBY = 128 WHERE SAMPLEID = " + sampleID + " AND TESTID = " + testID + " AND RUNID = 1";

                                            string upd2cmd = "UPDATE LIM_SAMPLETESTRESULTPROCESSES SET PROCESSSTATUS = 3.3, PROCESSCOMPLETEDT = SYSDATE, PROCESSCOMPLETEBY "
                                            + "= 128 WHERE SAMPLEID = " + sampleID + " AND TESTID = " + testID + " AND RUNID = 1";

                                            cmd1.CommandText = upd1cmd;
                                            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                            cmd1.CommandText = "COMMIT WORK";
                                            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                            cmd1.CommandText = upd2cmd;
                                            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                            cmd1.CommandText = "COMMIT WORK";
                                            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                        }

                                    }
                                    catch (Exception f)
                                    {
                                        //Log.Error("Problems with the field results.");
                                    }
                                }
```